# Apache2 doesn't want to start

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I want to run apache2 on my droplet instance at digitalocean, when i do :

```
sudo systemctl -l status apache2
```

This returns me

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor 
  preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
```

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-08-06 17:47:06 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 14601 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

```
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: (98)Address already in use: 
AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: (98)Address already in use: 
AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: no listening sockets available, 
shutting down
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus apachectl[14601]: The Apache error log may have 
more information.
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process 
exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.
Aug 06 17:47:06 kmplus systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

My aim is to install mysql and phpmyadmin but apache2 refuse to start and i am blocked.

Anyone can helps me please?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: It looks like there are two Listen directives for port 80 or port 443. Edit the config file of apache2, and correct the duplicate Listen directive.

config file: vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Option #2: execute the following command:

ss -plnt sport eq :80

Then kill the offending processes.

Also, you can check the logs of apache2 from the log file to investigate it further.

Comment: Hi, 
vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf gives me a blank file
the second option shows nginx on port 80

Comment: Could you please provide me the exact logs of apache2 so it will help to resolve the issue. It seems the config file of apache2 has located at another location.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, i just change nginx default port and all is running now.